# Is there a good way to recover the raid5 data

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, data-recovery, readynas

I am now trying to recover the raid data.

I have used 3 * 8TB HDD as RAID5.

Somehow, maybe one or two of them are broken.

In this case, I have bumped into the mdadm and pvscan,lvscan usecase.

What I have done is like this below.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md127 : inactive sdf2[2](S)
      523760 blocks super 1.2

md0 : inactive sdg1[1](S) sdd1[4](S) sde1[0](S)
      12570624 blocks super 1.2

md1 : inactive sdb2[2](S)
      523760 blocks super 1.2
```

then activate each drives.

```
mdadm -R /dev/md0
mdadm -R /dev/md1
mdadm -R /dev/md127
```

Every drives are activated.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid1] 
md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdf2[2]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [3/1] [__U]

md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdg1[1] sde1[0](F)
      4190208 blocks super 1.2 [4/1] [_U__]

md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb2[2]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [3/1] [__U]
```

then I try pvscan however these error happne. what can I do next to recover my data??please give me anyhelp.

```
sudo pvscan

  /dev/md0: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: input/output error
  /dev/md0: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4290707456: input/output error
  /dev/md0: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4290764800: input/output error
  /dev/md0: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: input/output error
  /dev/md1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: input/output error
  /dev/md1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 536215552: input/output error
  /dev/md1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 536272896: input/output error
  /dev/md1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: input/output error
  /dev/md127: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: input/output error
  /dev/md127: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 536215552: input/output error
  /dev/md127: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 536272896: input/output error
  /dev/md127: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: input/output error
  No matching physical volumes found
```

Comment: In a RAID 5 Array, if 2 or more of your drives fail, you will not be able to rebuild the array, resulting in a loss of all of the data in the array.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment above said, if you were using Raid5, your data is gone. Raid5 can only tolerate the loss of one single drive. Losing two drives breaks the array.

**However**, your configuration indicates that you are using Raid1 (mirroring) rather than Raid5 (striping + parity). Your data should still be okay.

Notice the output of /proc/mdstat:

```
md127 : active (auto-read-only) **raid1** sdf2[2]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [3/1] [__U]

md0 : active (auto-read-only) **raid1** sdg1[1] sde1[0](F)
      4190208 blocks super 1.2 [4/1] [_U__]

md1 : active (auto-read-only) **raid1** sdb2[2]
      523712 blocks super 1.2 [3/1] [__U]
```

Emphasis mine with the *'s.
These errors indicate that you've lost multiple drives from each array. Given that this is a mirror set, your data is still fine, but your system will run like garbage until the failed disks are replaced.

Notice the number next to each volume. [3/1] indicates it's a 3 disk array, but only one disk is available. The __U shows that the first and second disks in the array are down.

Judging by this output, you need to replace no less than 7 volumes. Two in md127, three in md0, and two in md1. [A full guide to running the appropriate commands can be found here.](https://www.howtoforge.com/replacing_hard_disks_in_a_raid1_array)

**Please note that you have no redundancy in either of these sets now. If you lose one more drive in either array, your data is toast. I would power this server down immediately until replacement drives can be sourced.**

#### Another option:

I don't know what happened to your system, but losing 7 drives seems like an excessive rate of failure especially if it came up all at once. This may indicate a problem with the storage controller, rather than the hard drives. If the server this is on has any kind of onboard diagnostics for the controller your drives are connected to, you should run those.